# The authenticated user has not granted the app xxxx89 write access to the file aaaaaxxxamc

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

i'm updateing files in gdrive from one account through drive api 
However when  i have create another account and assgin the same permission
I'm unable to upload files
please refere attached screen shot for the same

https://3dea925eff6caffb6aa84325890bf3da43e77e1d.googledrive.com/host/0B9vJUCqMBOjtLWwxSlhCSUJRaEE/as.png

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "fileAccess",
    "message": "The authenticated user has not granted the app xxxx189 write access to the file Asasavamc",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The authenticated user has not granted the app xxxxxx189 write access to the file asasasasRvamc"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Can you share more details on the OAuth flow and whether you're acting on a personal Gmail or a Google Apps account?
- Do you see the Service Account authorized under https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?

Update:

I recommend you to have a look at your OAuth flow and scope. Providing your code would be useful to pinpoint the issue. Here is a working example of deleting a file from Drive via App Engine:

```
import logging
import httplib2
import webapp2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2Decorator
from apiclient import errors

decorator = OAuth2Decorator(
  client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
  client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @decorator.oauth_required
    def get(self):
        # Get the authorized Http object created by the decorator.
        http = decorator.http()

        # Construct the drive client
        drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

        # Delete file
        try:
            drive_service.files().delete(fileId="FILE_ID").execute()
        except errors.HttpError, error:
            logging.error('An error occurred: %s' % error)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
                               (decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler())],
                              debug=True)
```

Comment: personal Gmail account and yes I can see my account under permissions

Comment: I tried and created different folder with file but still the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

Please update the scope values from `readonly to DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE, DriveScopes.DRIVE, and DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA`